# ESLint GitHub Action Fails on Vue2 (Works Locally)

Tags: vue.js, npm, github-actions, eslint

So I'm trying to get a Linter setup for this Vue2 app. I got it working locally, but so far I've been unable to get the GitHub action running correctly. It seems like it's finding ESLint, but then ESLint is saying it can't find the files to lint or something.

I'm using separate commands for local and pipeline linting, but that's because the command that I had configured for local didn't work on pipeline, so I separated them to troubleshoot the pipeline (and because I want local to have --fix and pipeline to *not* have --fix)

*package.json*:

```
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "pipeline-lint": "eslint ./** --config .eslintrc.json",
    "lint": "eslint --fix ../src/**"
  }
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.25.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.6.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    ...
  }
  ...
```

*lint.yml*:

```
name: ESLint Checks

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ develop ]
defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: src
jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install modules
        run: npm install
      - name: Run linter
        run: npm run pipeline-lint
```

**Resulting output in GitHub action output**:

```
2022-10-21T20:49:55.5002164Z added 1953 packages, and audited 1954 packages in 31s
2022-10-21T20:49:55.5003945Z 
2022-10-21T20:49:55.5004429Z 148 packages are looking for funding
2022-10-21T20:49:55.5005385Z   run `npm fund` for details
2022-10-21T20:49:55.5288453Z 
2022-10-21T20:49:55.5290427Z 23 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 19 high, 3 critical)
2022-10-21T20:49:55.5291227Z 
2022-10-21T20:49:55.5291923Z To address issues that do not require attention, run:
2022-10-21T20:49:55.5293496Z   npm audit fix
2022-10-21T20:49:55.5294719Z 
2022-10-21T20:49:55.5295715Z To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
2022-10-21T20:49:55.5297162Z   npm audit fix --force
2022-10-21T20:49:55.5297773Z 
2022-10-21T20:49:55.5298373Z Run `npm audit` for details.
2022-10-21T20:49:55.5643706Z ##[group]Run npm run pipeline-lint
2022-10-21T20:49:55.5644086Z [36;1mnpm run pipeline-lint[0m
2022-10-21T20:49:55.5705771Z shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
2022-10-21T20:49:55.5706084Z ##[endgroup]
2022-10-21T20:49:55.9275958Z 
2022-10-21T20:49:55.9278861Z > consumer-seller-frontend@1.0.0 pipeline-lint
2022-10-21T20:49:55.9279807Z > eslint ./** --config .eslintrc.json
2022-10-21T20:49:55.9280232Z 
2022-10-21T20:49:56.7124756Z 
2022-10-21T20:49:56.7125640Z Oops! Something went wrong! :(
2022-10-21T20:49:56.7125994Z 
2022-10-21T20:49:56.7126306Z ESLint: 8.25.0
2022-10-21T20:49:56.7126513Z 
2022-10-21T20:49:56.7128304Z No files matching the pattern "./app" were found.
2022-10-21T20:49:56.7129136Z Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.
2022-10-21T20:49:56.7176966Z 
2022-10-21T20:49:56.7345485Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's an issue with the Nuxt linter plugin - at least on the environment I'm using. This is the config that ended up working in the end:

```
...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "pipeline-lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.vue",
    "lint": "eslint --fix . --ext .js,.vue"
  }
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.6.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
    ...
  }
  ...
```

I had to specify the webpack version to prevent a build issue once the PR merged (shown in snippit), but otherwise this config solved the issue I was having.